# Type error in my own Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell, and after getting a basic grasp on some things about it, I tried to write a simple function which tests for the primality of a number n, and this is what I came up with:

```hs
isPrime n i = 
if n < 2
    then 0
    else if n == 2 || n == 3
         then 1
         else if    (n `mod` i) == 0
              then 0
              else if i == floor(sqrt(n))
                   then 1
                   else isPrime n (i + 1)
```

The algorithm itself seems to work (I tested it in another language), however when trying to call it for any number (i.e. *isPrime 5 2*), I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:9:1:
Could not deduce (Floating a10) arising from a use of `isPrime'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => a
  at <interactive>:9:1-11
The type variable `a10' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Floating Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
In the expression: isPrime 5 2
In an equation for `it': it = isPrime 5 2

<interactive>:9:9:
Could not deduce (Num a10) arising from the literal `5'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => a
  at <interactive>:9:1-11
The type variable `a10' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
  instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  ...plus three others
In the first argument of `isPrime', namely `5'
In the expression: isPrime 5 2
In an equation for `it': it = isPrime 5 2
```

I have tried to specify the types, like

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

but that just returns a different error, and can't even compile.

EDIT: here is the error of this version:

```
Prime.hs:10:48:
No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `floor'
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `floor (sqrt (n))'
In the expression: i == floor (sqrt (n))
In the expression:
  if i == floor (sqrt (n)) then 1 else isPrime n (i + 1)

Prime.hs:10:54:
No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `sqrt'
In the first argument of `floor', namely `(sqrt (n))'
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `floor (sqrt (n))'
In the expression: i == floor (sqrt (n))
```

Please help me, how should I change my code to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should try looking up `sqrt` in [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle) once

Comment: The error with the added type annotation is usually more insightful, and should point to the actual issue. You should add it to your post.

Comment: @chi I see, so sqrt actually needs a Floating type variable. But if I write `isPrime :: Double -> Double -> Double`, for example, then the `mod` function stops working, since that needs Integral type numbers..

Comment: @MrTsjolder wow, I had no idea this existed, it is very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality

```
i < sqrt n
```

can be rewritten without needing real numbers, and computed without needing an integer square root as

```
i^2 < n
```

or

```
i*i < n
```

This is enough to get your code to compile and work.

```
isPrime n i = 
    if n < 2
        then 0
        else if n == 2 || n == 3
             then 1
             else if    (n `mod` i) == 0
                  then 0
                  else if i*i < n
                       then isPrime n (i + 1)
                       else 1

main = print $ isPrime 13 2
```

You might want to change the signature so that it can be used more easily. If you change the return type to `Bool` and get rid of the second argument you can write things like `if isPrime 13 then ...` or `filter isPrime [1..30]`.

```
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime n = go n 2
    where
        go n i =
            if n < 2
                then False
                else if n == 2 || n == 3
                     then True
                     else if    (n `mod` i) == 0
                          then False
                          else if i*i < n
                               then go n (i + 1)
                               else True

main = print $ filter isPrime [1..30]
```

This leads towards the solution where we only check that the primes up through `sqrt n` don't divide `n`.

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = filter isPrime [1..]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = if n < 2
                then False
                else if n == 2 || n == 3
                     then True
                     else all (\i -> n `mod` i /= 0) . takeWhile (\i -> i*i <= n) $ primes

main = print $ take 10 primes
```

Since we are going to calculate `i*i` many times, we can justify taking the `sqrt n` instead. `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` operates on any `Floating` numbers. We can convert from integral numbers to any other number type with `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = filter isPrime [1..]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = if n < 2
                then False
                else if n == 2 || n == 3
                     then True
                     else all (\i -> n `mod` i /= 0) . takeWhile (<= root_n) $ primes
            where
                root_n = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n

main = print $ take 10 primes
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved the problem, though I still don't understand how should I fix the code using sqrt

Comment: I just saw your edit, and the function substitution with `go` is very useful! Also, originally I wrote it with `Bool`, just changed it for debugging.

Comment: Although inefficient, the way to compute the expression in non-integers is `fromIntegral`:

`i == (floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n)`

Comment: @PeterDam I was going to say that square root is generally a much slower operation than squaring an `Integer`... but then I tested briefly in GHCi and actually it was a bit faster... and even slightly with `Int`.

Comment: just going to leave a small ignorable unrelated note here that things like `if x then True else ..`, etc., are slightly redundant :)